# Content Service Crash

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I get weird exception:

10-31 09:09:51.308: ERROR/ContentService(59): Content Service Crash
10-31 09:09:51.308: ERROR/ContentService(59): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-31 09:09:51.308: ERROR/ContentService(59):     at android.content.ContentService$ObserverNode.collectObserversLocked(ContentService.java:620)
10-31 09:09:51.308: ERROR/ContentService(59):     at android.content.ContentService.notifyChange(ContentService.java:134)
10-31 09:09:51.308: ERROR/ContentService(59):     at android.content.IContentService$Stub.onTransact(IContentService.java:91)
10-31 09:09:51.308: ERROR/ContentService(59):     at android.content.ContentService.onTransact(ContentService.java:83)
10-31 09:09:51.308: ERROR/ContentService(59):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:288)
10-31 09:09:51.308: ERROR/ContentService(59):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

after that - only a restart of the emulator helps.
anyone knows what is this?

Ori

Comment: Yeah sure we know exactly what's going on, because this isn't actually a programming forum, it's a psychic forum

Comment: Unless you can give us some code that triggers this exception, I doubt anyone can help you.

Comment: getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("some_string"),    false, _refreshObserver);

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use arbitrary strings with `Uri.parse()` and expect it to work. The `Uri` needs to be a real `Uri` supplied by a real content provider.

Comment: more exact - you need the Uri be of the form: content://com.provider.path/some_string